# Did Rāma have Kuja doṣa? What about the Pāṇḍavas?

Tags: krishna, rama, astrology, pandavas

Did Rāma have Kuja doṣa (a.k.a  maṅgala doṣa, māṅgalika)? What about the Pāṇḍavas?

I see all of them exiled to the woods in their prime years. This must be the worst thing that can happen to a kṣatriya.

Rāma even got separated from his wife, Sītā, not once but twice. At least the Pāṇḍavas always had Draupadī accompanying them wherever they went.

If Rāma did have Kuja doṣa, how come Vasiṣṭa or Śatānanda didn't know about it? Why did they approve Rāma's marriage with Sītā?

Also, what about Kṛṣṇa? Did he have Kuja doṣa?

Comment: When we see ValmikiRamayana 1.18 we find that Mars was in 7th house from ascendant [eg. [Here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8414/%e0%a4%b0%e0%a4%be%e0%a4%b6%e0%a4%bfzodiac-sign-of-krishna-and-rama/11745#11745) ] Mãngalik is considered when Mars is from 1, 4, 7, 8 and 12 from ascendant. But I'm not sure whether there was concept of Mãnglik in Ramas era or not... In any case it was destiny that Sita would be married to Rama as they are eternal consorts...

Comment: Rama lived in Treta yuga when people lived a lot longer so the 14 prime years of life is quite different. Dasharatha is known to have reigned for 60,000 years. I believe Rama ruled for 11,000 years. The period of separation from Sita was the last year of vanavaasa, and more the second time.

Comment: @user1952500 IMHO, those are exaggerated #'s, poetic way of saying they ruled for a really long time. Please read this [answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16039).

Answer (score 3):

Yes technically he did have Kuja dosha. 
Mars was placed in 7th house in an exalted position. He was born under Cancer ascendant. Though it should be considered that Mars was exalted.

Ramayana described Bhagavan Sri Rama’s birth time in these slokas (Sansckrit verses)

> Madhu maase, sithe pakshe, Navamyaam, Karkate subhe, Punarvas
>   nakshathra sahithe, utchasthe graha-pamchake ! Mesahm Pooshani
>   samprapthe, pushpavrushti samakule, aviraasee Jagannaatha,
>   Parama-atmaa, sanaathanaha =
>
> During the Spring season of Vasantha-ruthu (madhumaase means Chaithra
>   month; in April), Sukla paksha (waxing Moon), Navami thithi (9th day
>   after new-moon), in Karkaataka lagna (Cancer is birth house;
>   ascendant) . in Punarvasu star (Moon is in Punarvasu star in Cancer;
>   so Cancer is also Rasi-lagna (Moon); Cancer is own house for Moon)
>   when 5 planets were in exaltation and when Sun was in Mesha (Aries)
>   Bhagavan Sri Jagannaath (the Supreme Lord of Universe was born; then
>   sweet-scented flowers rained profusely for one muhurtha (duration of
>   12 minutes) from the sky on the castle where Sri Rama was born. The
>   time of birth was described based on Lunar System of Vedic astrology.
>   Sun stays in Aries during Mesha month (roughly from April—14 to May—14
>   ) of every year.

[Ref](http://jyothishi-pandit.blogspot.co.ke/2010/03/bhagavan-sri-ramachandra-horoscope_24.html)