# Stars of hindu gods

Tags: gods, nakshatra

I need to know about the birth stars of the hindu gods. How and where i can get the legit informations. Can you help me in this?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to HSE.!! Please visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se), to get familiar with our site. Further, kindly have a look at: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Have an enriching Journey ahead.

Comment: Related to your question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8414/%e0%a4%b0%e0%a4%be%e0%a4%b6%e0%a4%bfzodiac-sign-of-krishna-and-rama/11746#11746

Comment: You need to specify exactly which gods you want to know the stars of. Since there can be many gods asking about all in one question makes the question closeable as "too broad" or "needs clarity".